# Sharepoint 2010 Web Services: Authentication using WCF failing

Tags: wcf, web-services, sharepoint, visual-c++

I am creating an application to list all sub sites, attributes and to upload documents. I am trying to use WCF to use sharepoint web services. 
TO authenticate i have written the below mentioned code:

```
HRESULT hr;
ISAXXMLReader* pRdr = NULL;
hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
hr = CoCreateInstance(
                __uuidof(SAXXMLReader),
                NULL,
                CLSCTX_ALL,
                __uuidof(ISAXXMLReader),
                (void **)&pRdr);

 if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
 {
    pRdr->putBaseURL(L"http://bascansp01");
    Authentication::CAuthentication* auth = new Authentication::CAuthentication(pRdr);  
    Authentication::LoginResult* res = new Authentication::LoginResult();

    BSTR sUsername  = L"aakanksh@abc";
    BSTR sPasswd    = L"abcd";
    hr = auth->Login(sUsername, sPasswd, res);
```

but my login is failing. While debugging i found out that it failes at the line:
__atlsoap_hr = SendRequest(_T("SOAPAction: \"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/Login\"\r\n"));

any clue why it is failing.

Thanks and Regards,
Aakanksha